# Generate text file from change set details in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have database script folder in TFS.Developers add and changed the script files. I want to generate single text file when I specify the two change sets. Is there any possibility doing that in TFS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TFS API to query the code history, and pull out the data that way (you'd have to write the code to do this yourself).

The better way to manage updating databases is to use a [Visual Studio Database Project (aka SSDT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/tools.aspx) and let the tooling do this for you.